# Generating static map from python code

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

The following python code works but i don't know how to display the driving directions in a browser using google maps. I have no clue to proceed. Hints are welcome.

```
import googlemaps
import datetime

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key)

# Geocoding and address
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')

# Look up an address with reverse geocoding
reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((40.714224, -73.961452))

# Request directions via public transit
now = datetime.datetime.now()
directions_result = gmaps.directions("Sydney Town Hall",
                                     "Parramatta, NSW",
                                     mode="transit",
                                     departure_time=now)

print directions_result
```

Here is the print output of directions_result (**NOT FULLY SHOWN TO CONSERVE SPACE**)

[{u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u'lzvmEsr{y[m@EO|@Z??KGQNK`@EVB`@D@KTBMBHCKRT@bCVnAZvCXjAE^GXOnBcBbDiDzAeApAq@|@WhBWZCf@F`ALpEr@pF`Ax@R|Bv@d@Tt@h@bAz@l@d@NJIMHLlBvAVRv@r@~@bAz@hAz@vAVTPTRf@Xf@`BdCpCbEfAtAj@j@hDhC`BrAhDtCxAnAtArApB~Bd@n@v@rAn@xAbEtKf@zAb@zAZvA^rBXlB^bCfF`U`AvDnA~Dn@|Bf@vC^pCl@jCXdB`@zCRfCHfCDjMOpFClCKhCWpBq@xCk@fBm@|AaAnByAjCs@`BcArD{@nDwA~Em@bC]rB[~CEjBAnAB`BTbFZhEb@rEN`C@zCSfD]hCwAxG[xBW|CE~BJ`EdArLHpCC`D_@zFg@nFObAUrAy@hDo@pC}@jE}AvG}@pDw@nDe@rBkArE_BdFo@|Bg@fCo@vEOjBIbCSjKOfHG~AKbAUzBYrBe@`C{@pDkBxHeAzDo@zCq@rC{B|Iy@`Ey@jD}AdGuAlEsAfDwDhI}BfFaAfB}AdCyCnFaA`BmAdBkE~F}AtBuAvBeAlB}@vBm@lBk@xBqBrK[vB[bCw@~Hu@nHSpAe@nB[`As@fBuArC_@l@q@x@kBnBgAjAsAlAaAx@}@`Au@~@s@jA{AbDy@zAm@x@QRACbAn@`@a@fAPH^Q|@k@bG{B_@m@Sc@[qCmDI@IIuBxB[RQDq@CoRyFeAh@QXa@pCSnBiAlIsAhIwBbKoAjFiC`JyArEqGzQmT`m@m@xBi@`Cc@pC{@nLo@`H{ArIgD`LaF`N}EbLoEnJqCfFaBrC{DhGaa@jj@uBnDcAvBmEdKmJlUuM`\\}@rC[xA_@jAg@~@eA|AqChD}CrG{AxDqAdEqAvFiBfJmBdI@LaA~CiCzFm@fB]bBc@`E}DqBsBy@aAS}EUwSs@c_@yCoDSw@|H_Cle@D`AHr@nAxDV~ADv@Aj@c@xK?b@@ZXxAz@zDZ`A}C~Bw@L{Ad@g@^o@x@QLm@JBxCaAbDHDKCMp@WzA?\@FJJqAP_Cd@{@f@s@FJq@'}, u'warnings': [u'Walking directions are in beta.    Use caution \u2013 This route may be missing sidewalks or pedestrian paths.'], u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': -33.8150365, u'lng':

**(NOT FULLY SHOWN TO CONSERVE SPACE)**

Comment: It is unfair to -ve rep without a plausible explanation. We need to be open to diverse questions. Not everyone is perfect in English or formatting.

Comment: Not a downvoter but I did vote to close... I can't tell if the user is asking for help writing code to call Python's webbrowser.open (meaning python is running as a client) or to return html to the browser (meaning python is running as a web service).  I would lean toward the former, but in that case, SO is still not a code-writing service, so asker should show what's he tried.

Comment: @Foon. Thanks. It would be great if both ways are told. I don't have a clue how to return html from above code